# Proving injectivity but not surjectivity in a countably infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a countably infinite set. Prove that there is a function $f: X \rightarrow X$ that is injective, but not surjective. 
I know that for the function to be injective each $x$ in $X$ must work in the function $f(x)=x$. I also know that for the function to not be surjective, there must exist an $x$ in $X$ such that $f^{-1}(x)$ does not equal $x$.

Comment: Suggest you look up exact definition of surjective.. it isn't what you have it as in the question. Also what does "each x in X works in the function" mean? So also suggest you look up injective.

Answer (score 5):

Given that $X$ is countably infinite, we can list the elements of $X$ as $x_1, x_2, x_3,...$. Now define the following mapping from $X$ to $X$: $ f(x_i) = x_{i+1}$ for all numbers $i$. It is easy to show that this $f$ is injective but not surjective.

Comment: Equivalently let $g:\mathbb N\to X$ be a bijection, and let $f(x)=g(1+g^{-1}(x))$  for $x\in X.$